# VB script syntax issue in IE 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, vbscript

I'm facing an issue when I tried to run my automation script on a IE 9 browser (but works fine in IE 10 and 11).

The issue is, I'm unable to access the HTML element through a syntax which I followed for the newer versions of IE.

Here is the code syntax which works fine in IE 10 & 11

```
    Set objInputs = internalContent.getElementsByClassName("linkedlinks")
    Set objElement = objInputs(0)     <-- this is where I'm facing the error -->
```

I am trying to get the first element among the list of HTML DOM elements, but the script is throwing an error in IE 9 browsers alone.
**Note**: I verified  the length of the objInputs; it is more than one. As I said, it works fine in IE 10 and 11

I'm getting the following error when the execution comes to that line.

[image]

**Hint**: What I think could be the possible solution is, the syntax could be changed a little in order to be supported in IE 9.

I need a way to access the **first** element alone from the list of elements got through 'getElementsByClassName'.

I tried

```
    Set objElement = objInputs.Item(0)
```

which didn't work as well. So can anyone kindly help me fix this issue. I'm struck here for the past few weeks; I tried a lot already.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname, IE9 supports `getElementsByClassName`.

Are you in "standards" mode? Try adding `<!doctype html>` to the top of your document.

**EDIT: Sample page (tested in IE9)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
    Function DoClick()
        Set e = document.getElementsByClassName("mytest")
        MsgBox e.length    ' ==> "3"
        MsgBox e(0).id     ' ==> "s1"   
    End Function
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <span class="mytest" id="s1"></span>
    <span class="mytest" id="s2"></span>
    <span class="mytest" id="s3"></span>
    <input type="button" language="vbscript" onclick="DoClick" value="VBScript Test" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually the script is for the IE automation, so I have the script code in a (.vbs) file. 

"getElementsByClassName" works fine; I confirmed it using "objInputs.length". I'm getting the correct values but while trying to access the first element, I'm getting the error (the one in the screenshot).

I tried using 

        Set objElement = objInputs.Item(0)
 and 
        Set objElement = objInputs[0]
but it seems, these syntaxes are not allowed.

Comment: @user3005271 Where is your page content coming from? Are you adding it programmatically via your VBScript?

Comment: Its my client's web page. I'm developing an automation tool for that website. Its a server page with iframes in it. I found the problem is due to the TypeName of the object obtained through "getElementsByClassName". The object is of type - "JscriptTypeInfo" which is not traversable through vbscript. I'm trying to find a way to do that.